# Access module 'sys' without using import machinery

Tags: python, sandbox, exploit

Sandboxing Python code is notoriously difficult due to the power of the reflection facilities built into the language.  At a minimum one has to take away the `import` mechanism and most of the built-in functions and global variables, and even then there are holes (`{}.__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()`, for instance).

In both Python 2 and 3, the 'sys' module is built into the interpreter and preloaded before user code begins to execute (even in `-S` mode).  If you can get a handle to the `sys` module, then you have access to the global list of loaded modules (`sys.modules`) which enables you to do all sorts of naughty things.

So, the question: Starting from an empty module, without using the import machinery *at all* (no `import` statement, no `__import__`, no `imp` library, etc), and also without using anything normally found in `__builtins__` unless you can get a handle to it some other way, is it possible to acquire a reference to either `sys` or `sys.modules`?  (Each points to the other.)  Am interested in both 2.x and 3.x answers.

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/looking_for_python_3_builtins.html gives you access to `__builtins__`, giving you access to `__import__`, giving you access to `sys`.

Comment: Arguably this is a dupe of [can you recover from reassigning \_\_builtins\_\_ in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13307110)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Argh, I meant to specify no `__import__`, no `imp`, etc.  Will edit.

Comment: Without import, you need to find a `__globals__` with `sys` in it. Not much harder.

Comment: But you can't just state *no `__import__`*. You don't have a choice about that, you can *recover* `__import__` by recovering `__builtins__`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__builtins__` can usually be recovered, giving you a path back to `__import__` and thus to any module.

For Python 3 [this comment from eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307110/can-you-recover-from-reassigning-builtins-in-python/13307417#comment18155424_13307417) works, for example:

```
>>> f = [t for t in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() 
...      if t.__name__ == 'Sized'][0].__len__
>>> f.__globals__['__builtins__']['__import__']('sys')
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

In Python 2, you just [look for a different object](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201302/looking_for_python_3_builtins.html):

```
>>> f = [t for t in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
...      if t.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0].__exit__.__func__
>>> f.__globals__['__builtins__']['__import__']('sys')
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Either method looks for subclasses of a built-in type you can create with literal syntax (here a tuple), then referencing a function object on that subclass. Function objects have a `__globals__` dictionary reference, which will give you the `__builtins__` object back.

Note that you can't just say *no `__import__`* because it is part of `__builtins__` *anyway*.

However, many of those `__globals__` objects are bound to have `sys` present *already*. Searching for a `sys` module on Python 3, for example, gives me access to one in a flash:

```
>>> next(getattr(c, f).__globals__['sys']
...      for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
...      for f in dir(c)
...      if isinstance(getattr(c, f, None), type(lambda: None)) and
...         'sys' in getattr(c, f).__globals__)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

The Python 2 version only need to unwrap the unbound methods you find on classes to get the same results:

```
>>> next(getattr(c, f).__func__.__globals__['sys']
...      for c in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
...      for f in dir(c)
...      if isinstance(getattr(c, f, None), type((lambda: 0).__get__(0))) and
...         'sys' in getattr(c, f).__func__.__globals__)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
```