# How to get __import__ back after removing it with del __builtins__.__dict__["__import__"]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying out a coding challange right now. I cannot change the code before
`del __builtins__.__dict__["__import__"]` but must use import afterwards. I need a way to restore the default `__builtins__`. Its python 2.7.

I tryed `__builtins__ = [x for x in (1).__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if x.__name__ == 'catch_warnings'][0]()._module.__builtins__` but that doesn't work because the reference to **builtins** hasn't gone but the element from the dictionary of builtins are.

Comment: **Patient**: Doctor, it hurts when I do this. **Doctor**: Don't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you recover from reassigning \_\_builtins\_\_ in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307110/can-you-recover-from-reassigning-builtins-in-python)

Comment: I'm curious.  What's the point of this "coding challenge"?

Comment: @PeterWood won't work, since `__builtins__` is a reference to the same namespace in every module.

Comment: @Steve The actual challange is simpler but I would like to get extra points. https://hacking-lab.com/cases/5138-escape-from-python-city/5138-escape-from-python-city-wargame.html?event=199&case=990

Comment: @roboalex2 Unfortunately, that link requires a login/password to view the challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, you can use the `reload` function to get a fresh copy of the `__builtins__` module:

```
>>> del __builtins__.__dict__['__import__']
>>> reload(__builtins__)
<module '__builtin__' (built-in)>
>>> __import__
<built-in function __import__>
>>>
```

In Python 3, the `reload` function has been moved to the `imp` module (and in Python 3.4, `importlib`) so importing `imp` or `importlib` isn't option without `__import__`. Instead, you can use `__loader__.load_module` to load the `sys` module and delete the cached but ruined copy of the `builtins` module from the `sys.modules` dict, so that you can load a new copy of the `builtins` module with `__loader__.load_module`:

```
>>> del __builtins__.__dict__['__import__']
>>> del __loader__.load_module('sys').modules['builtins']
>>> __builtins__ = __loader__.load_module('builtins')
>>> __import__
<built-in function __import__>
>>>
```

Comment: I would have thought ugly problems would require ugly solutions, but this seems beautiful in a way.

Comment: @blhsing It's a real elegenate solution. But unfortunately not for me. I forgot to mention that it is Python 2.7. I'm sorry.