# limited eval function failing - how to import selected modules

Tags: python, function, lambda, eval

I want to attach functional stubs to a data process job I've written, and it would be convenient to be able to apply these via config file.

I can load and run these by means of the `eval` function, but want to be able to control the available namespace "sandbox" in which the evaluated functions can operate, so I can avoid malicious code injection.

In the python docs, it suggests blocking off `__builtins__` and then populating either (or is it both? it's not clear) globals and locals as dictionaries containing the objects in the execution namespace.

When I do this, the code I had been running successfully stops working.

I *think* this is because one of my test lambdas is referencing functions normally imported from the `datetime` module - but it's not clear to me how to get these to successfully attach to the namespace.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
lambdas = { "Report Date" : "lambda x : now.strftime(\"%d/%m/%Y\")",
             "Scary Test"  : "lambda x : os.curdir " }

compiled_funcs = {k:eval(v) for k,v in lambdas.items()}

compiled_funcs ['Report Date'](1)
>>> '15/04/2019'

compiled_funcs ['Scary Test'](1)
>>> '.'
```

Now, I want to edit the `eval()` function to limit the available scope so that the datetime function continues to work, but the `os` module fails (if I can call an os command, then I could do something scary like wipe the disk, or worse)

I have tried constructions like:

```
compiled_funcs = {k:eval(v,{'__builtins__':None, "now" : now, "datetime" : datetime, } , { }) for k,v in lambdas.items()}
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__import__'`

Which suggests that somewhere/somehow, the function I want to apply is trying to call/import some content down the line - and (presumably) this is correctly being blocked by having borked the `__builtins__` content. Is there a way to pre-package such functions and inject them into the eval globals, or locals dictionaries to enable a pre-defined set of functional tools?

Once I've got this working, I should be able to extend it so I can curate my own subset of safe function calls to be exposed to this run-time collection from configuration files.

N.B. I know in the above, I could define my lambdæ with no arguments - but in my real code, it would be normal to feed a single parameter, so have built my test code accordingly.

Comment: Blocking off `__builtins__` isn't going to make `eval` safer because one can still access `__builtins__` from attributes of a built-in object, as demonstrated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307110/can-you-recover-from-reassigning-builtins-in-python .

Comment: OK, so I guess my usecase is that the code being injected is "semi-trusted" in that it's not going to be written by someone who can't be sacked or otherwise held responsible. i.e. Not unlike someone writing "real" code for execution. So I suppose maybe closing down `__builtins__` could just be a cosmetic bit of fluff that would only deter a cursory attempt at mischief...food for thought...also thanks for the link - it contains a few interesting linked articles itself.